# How to get data in express js

Tags: node.js, express

For the first time ever i am trying to understand expressJs and I have testing route which returns simple test sentence as JSON, but i can't get in in expressJs.

`test.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('https://mysite.ccc/api/test', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json(data)
});

module.exports = router;
```

`apps.js`

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var testRouter = require('./routes/test'); ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////here

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/test', testRouter); ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////here

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I'm not sure but i guess it suppose to show my api sentence in `http://127.0.0.1:3000/test` instead with:

this command: `set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start` it says: `404 not found`

and with this command `npm start` it says `request is not defined`

**what did i do wrong?**

Comment: You need to use only a slash here like this `router.get('/',...`

Comment: @SuleymanSah then where should i call my url?

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/test` will map to that route

Comment: Or do you want to call your api there?

Comment: @SuleymanSah i mean this url `https://mysite.ccc/api/test` this is where my data comes from

Comment: You need to call your api inside the function body

Comment: would you mind show me how? it's my first time with express :)

Comment: You can use axios or request packages,  just search google `how to call api in express`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‍ You can change your `test.js` with this code below:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var axios = require('axios');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://mysite.ccc/api/test');
    console.log(response.data);
    res.json(response.data)
  }catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex)
    res.status(400).send(ex.message);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I hope it's can help .

Comment: it fails with this error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: It's mean you forget to add `async` function. **You can copy and paste** that code above in your test.js

Comment: now in browser it says `Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest' | property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket' --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle`

Comment: That's why I add console.log in there, so you can see what the data from response you want to get. I've been update my answer.

Comment: with your edit it shows the data, `ps` nothing prints in console.

Comment: sorry quick question: how do i set page title for it? `res.json(response.data,{title="Test Page"})` this doesn't work

Comment: You have to make something like this: `const myResponse = { data: response.data, title: 'Test page"}` and then `res.json(myResponse)`.

Comment: Or you can make something like this: res.status(200).send({ data: response.data, title: 'Test page'})

Comment: hmm, both ways show data like this `{"data":"hi, this is for testing only.","title":"Test page"}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206563/discussion-between-titus-sutio-fanpula-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 1):

Your `test.js` file should look like this

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // I don't see where you defined data, should be smth like: const data = {};
  res.json(data);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here you define your route, so when you start your app you are able to access the route `http://127.0.0.1:3000/test`.

You probably want to retrieve data from external website? For this you can use any http package, for example `axios`.

Your final `test.js` file will look like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var axios = require('axios');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  const response = await axios.get('https://mysite.ccc/api/test');
  res.json(response.data);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Note: I hope you somewhere call `app.listen(3000)` to start your web server.

Comment: Thank you, already up voted but accepted other answer cause it uses `try{...}` appreciate it